# Django User model Filefield update error

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

So I have a user model one to one field with two filefields, I have no problem uploading the two files, but when I tried to change the file I get this :
[image: Logo]

**model.py** :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    demand_file = models.FileField(upload_to='archivos', blank=True, validators=[validate_file_extension])
    order_file = models.FileField(upload_to='archivos', blank=True, validators=[validate_file_extension])
```

**view.py**

```
@login_required
def upload_files(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserFileUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            profile = form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = request.user
            profile.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Archivo no valido, por favor ingrese un archivo CSV')
            return render(request, 'project_app/file_upload.html', {'uploads': form})
    else:

        form = UserFileUploadForm()
        return render(request, 'project_app/file_upload.html', {'uploads': form})
```

**forms.py**

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password')


class UserFileUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('demand_file', 'order_file')
```

And in console I get

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: project_app_profile.user_id

So I am doing something wrong, just cant see what.
anyways, thanks for any help you may provide.

Comment: try the code  `profile.user_id = request.user.id`

Comment: Thanks, but that gave me a "Profile has no user." @AnjaneyuluBatta